# Cannot access 'id' from debugger

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building React app and I've got an error "Cannot access 'id' from deugger" but I have no idea from where it comes. Here is how the error looks like:

[image]

And here is how the code `menu-button` look like:

[image]

Does anyone have an idea to what it might be related?